# Output parameter value wrong

Tags: sql, parameters, sqlcommand, output-parameter

I am passing a value to a parameter in a Stored Procedure and also declaring it's direction as `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`. In the Stored Procedure, the parameter is also declared as an OUTPUT parameter and the value being returned from the Stored Procedure is correct. I know this because I have tested executing the Stored Procedure on its own and using `PRINT` to display different values throughout the procedure. Also, the final part of the Stored Procedure inserts a record into the database using the value that I am expecting to be returned and that is appearing as expected. However, when I attempt to retrieve the value from the parameter after the `SqlCommand` has been executed, the value is still the previous value that I passed to the Stored Procedure. I have done this before and I am sure I've done it no differently. Here's a part of my command:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", Conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ImageFileNameNoExt
cmd.Parameters("@FileName").Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
ImageFileName = cmd.Parameters("@FileName").Value
```

Here, I am expecting `ImageFileName` to be the value of the `@FileName` parameter, returned from the Stored Procedure. However, it's still the same value as `ImageFileNameNoExt` which was passed to the procedure in the first place.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ContentPages_Images_Update]
    @PageID int
    ,@FileName nvarchar(100) OUTPUT
    ,@Ext nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --As the FileName is a unique key, ensure that the value being entered into the database will be unique.
    --If its not, then we can generate a new one
    SET @FileName = REPLACE(@FileName, ' ', '-')
    DECLARE @i int
            ,@FileNameCheck nvarchar(200)
    SET @i = 2
    SET @FileNameCheck = @FileName + @Ext
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [ContentPages_Images]
        WHERE [FileName]=@FileNameCheck
        AND (@PageID IS NULL OR NOT @PageID=ID)
        ) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @FileNameCheck = @FileName + '-' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(3)) + @Ext
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    SET @FileName = @FileNameCheck

    --Get new layout value
    DECLARE @Layout int
    SET @Layout = 1
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ContentPages_Images] WHERE PageID=@PageID) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Layout = (SELECT MAX(Layout) FROM [ContentPages_Images] WHERE PageID=@PageID) + 1
    END

    INSERT INTO [ContentPages_Images]
    (PageID, [FileName], [Layout])
    VALUES
    (@PageID, @FileName, @Layout)

END
```

Comment: provide your sql procedure code, if you can

Comment: There are a couple of parameter assignments missing in your code. `@PageID` and `@Ext`.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson Yeah that's ok thanks, I just originally showed the filename part because that was the part that wasn't working. The other 2 parameters are also passed.

Comment: Post *real* code, not what you feel is appropriate. Your edits/changes can hide the problem and make it more difficult to get answers. It can also lead to people wasting their time trying to help you, only to find out "it's not really the code. Thanks anyway. The problem is...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because you haven't specified a size for the parameter. Try changing your code to include the parameter's size like the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = ImageFileNameNoExt
```

Comment: I have just given this a try and it has worked! That's great, thanks very much for your help. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Leah Because `nvarchar` is a variable length data type, the length being set is the same as the length of the string being inputted. Therefore if the string is `StackOverflow`, the data length will be set to `13`. If `StackOverflow` is then changed to `StackOverflow-2`, this is now 15 characters long, and will be truncated to 13 to fit the parameter datatype. Hope this helps :)